# S式に変換したJSONデータに簡単にアクセスする方法

Tags: json, elisp, lisp

emacs24では`json.el`というJSONライブラリが標準で付属しています。これはエンコーダとデコーダのみを提供しており、変換後のS式をどのように扱うかはユーザ毎に異なります。

S式の要素を参照するための関数として`car/cdr/assoc/elt`等が用意されています。ただし、これらを多用するとパッと見てどこを参照しているのか分かりにくいように思えます。

```
;; FILE.json の中身
;; {
;;   "foo": {
;;    "bar": [1, 2, 3]
;;   }
;; }
(require 'json)
(let* ((json-key-type 'string)
       (json (json-read-file "FILE.json")))
  ;; json -> (("foo" ("bar" . [1 2 3])))
  (elt (cdr (assoc "bar" (cdr (assoc "foo" json)))) 0)
;=> 1
```

そこで、ネストしたS式に対して `(json "foo" "bar" 0)` のように簡単にアクセスできる書き方（あるいはライブラリ）はあるでしょうか？ライブラリであればMELPA等でパッケージ配布されていると尚良いです。

質問ではElispを対象にしていますが、他のLISP系言語ではS式に変換したJSONやXMLをどのように扱っているのか、参考にできそうな方法を知っていたら教えてほしいです。

Answer (score 8):

「他のLISP系言語ではS式に変換したJSONやXMLをどのように扱っているのか」について。

SaitoAtsushiさんがGaucheにjsonpathを移植しています。

http://saito.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/06/20/233036

ただ、JSONの緩さのために、XPathのような使い勝手にはならないようですが：

http://saito.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/06/25/095332

XMLについては、Scheme間でポータブルなXPathの実装SXPathがわりと使われていると思います。

Answer (score 2):

以下の様な function を使うのはいかがでしょうか。

```
(defun find-json-value (node json)
  (let* ((key (car node))
         (next (cdr node))
         (rest (and (listp (cdr json))
                    (assoc key json))))
    (if (and key next rest)
        (find-json-value next rest)
      (cdr rest))))

(find-json-value '("foo" "bar") json)
=> [1 2 3]
```

単に assoc-list を探索するだけのものですが、ご参考までにどうぞ。

Answer (score 2):

「他のLISP系言語ではS式に変換したJSONやXMLをどのように扱っているのか」について、その２。JSONのみですが。

R6RS Scheme処理系であれが、[json-tools](https://github.com/ktakashi/json-tools)もあります。これは[JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#overview)のScheme版で、CSSセレクタ風のJSONアクセスとSXPathに影響を受けたAPIを提供しています。

Answer (score 2):

MELPA で配布されている Key-Value ライブラリ `kv.el` に連想リストのドットアクセス用関数 `kvdotassoc` (`dotassoc`), `kvdotassq` (`dotassq`) が用意されています。

https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-kv

連想リストのキーはシンボル `foo.bar` と文字列 `"foo.bar"` の両方を扱え、キーのネストも可能です。ただし配列要素のアクセスには対応していません。

```
(let ((json (json-read-file "FILE.json")))
  ;; json -> ((foo (bar . [1 2 3])))
  (print (dotassoc 'foo json))          ;-> ((bar . [1 2 3]))
  (print (dotassoc 'foo.bar json))      ;-> [1 2 3]
  (print (dotassoc 'abc.xyz json))      ;-> nil
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

ネストした構造をたぐるのは、Clojureの`get-in`やRubyの`dig`のような感じですね。

Clojureの`get-in`のインターフェイスをまねてみると、こんな感じでしょうか。

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun get-in (dat keys)
  (cl-reduce
   (lambda (x k) (if (vectorp x) (elt x k) (cdr (assoc k x))))
   keys :initial-value dat ))

(get-in json '("foo" "bar" 0))
;;=> 1
(get-in json ["foo" "bar" 0])
;;=> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`let-alist`というELPAパッケージを見つけたので紹介しておきます。

http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/let-alist.html

このパッケージを利用すると、`(cdr (assq KEY ALIST))` という記述の代わりに `.KEY` のようなドット付きシンボルでアクセス可能になります。シンボルのネストもできます。

ただしパッケージ名の通り、取り扱うデータは連想リスト（なおかつキーがシンボル）のみで配列等にアクセスする機能は提供されてません。

```
(require 'let-alist)
(let-alist (json-read-file "FILE.json")
  (print .foo)                 ;-> ((bar . [1 2 3]))
  (print .foo.bar)             ;-> [1 2 3]
  (print (elt .foo.bar 0))     ;-> 1
)
```

任意のJSONを扱えるわけではないため、あくまで参考程度です。

Answer (score 0):

dash と dash-functional で次のような形に書くこともできます。 clojure で有名らしい threading macro らしいです。

```
(->>
 (json-read-from-string "{\"foo\":{\"bar\":[1,2,3]}}")
 (funcall (-compose 'cdr (-partial 'assoc 'foo)))
 (funcall (-compose 'cdr (-partial 'assoc 'bar)))
 (funcall (-flip 'elt) 0)
 )

;; => 1
```